# Improper broadcasting(?) on dataframe multiply() operation on two multindex slices

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to `multipy()` two multilevel slices of a dataframe, however I'm unable to coerce the multiply operation to broadcast properly, so I just end up with lots of nans.  It's like somehow I'm not specifying the indexing properly.

I've tried all variations of both `axis` and `level` but it eithers throws an exception or gives me a 6x6 grid of `Nan`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
idx = pd.IndexSlice


df_a = pd.DataFrame(index=range(6), 
                    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['weight', ], ['alice','bob', 'sue']], 
                                                       names=['measure','person']),
                    data=np.random.randint(70, high=120, size=(6,3), dtype=int)
                   )
df_a.index.name= "m"

df_b = pd.DataFrame(index=range(6), 
                    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['coef', ], ['alice','bob', 'sue']], 
                                                       names=['measure','person']),
                    data=np.random.rand(6,3)
                   )
df_b.index.name= "m"

df_c = pd.DataFrame(index=range(6), 
                    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['extraneous', ], ['alice','bob', 'sue']], 
                                                       names=['measure','person']),
                    data=np.random.rand(6,3)
                   )
df = df_a.join([df_b, df_c])

# What I'm wanting:
# new column = coef*weight
#measure   NewCol
#person    alice   bob   sue
#m
#0         30.2    48.1   88.9
#...
#5         18.3    32.2   103

#all of these variations generatea  6x6 grid of NaNs
df.loc[:,idx['weight',:]].multiply(df.loc[:,idx['coef',:]], axis="rows", )  
df.loc[:,idx['weight',:]].multiply(df.loc[:,idx['coef',:]], axis="colums", )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try via `to_numpy()` If you want to assign changes back to DataFrame:

```
df.loc[:,idx['weight',:]]=df.loc[:,idx['weight',:]].to_numpy()*df.loc[:,idx['coef',:]].to_numpy()

#you can also use values attribute
```

**OR**

If you want to create a new MultiIndexed column then use `concat()`+`join()`:

```
df=df.join(pd.concat([df['coef'].mul(df['weight'])],keys=['NewCol'],axis=1))
#OR
#df=df.join(pd.concat({'NewCol': df['coef'].mul(df['weight'])},axis=1))
```

Comment: Why does the `.multiply` not work with the `.loc` notation, but `df['coef'].mul(df['weight'])` does work?

Comment: @user3556757 possibly because of multiindex

Comment: Yes, selecting on a multiindex removes one level, so the resulting frame is different and the multiplication cannot find common indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `pandas.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([df,
                pd.concat({'NewCol': df['coef'].mul(df['weight'])},
                          axis=1)],
               axis=1)
```

output:

```
measure weight               coef                     extraneous                         NewCol                      
person   alice bob  sue     alice       bob       sue      alice       bob       sue      alice        bob        sue
m                                                                                                                    
0          107  98   89  0.906243  0.761173  0.754762   0.889252  0.140435  0.708203  96.968045  74.594927  67.173827
1          106  77  117  0.193279  0.138338  0.699014   0.826331  0.087769  0.242337  20.487623  10.652021  81.784634
2          104  77  101  0.340416  0.131111  0.394653   0.465670  0.825667  0.624923  35.403258  10.095575  39.859948
3           80  92  116  0.329999  0.144878  0.794014   0.539082  0.968411  0.588952  26.399889  13.328731  92.105674
4           75  76  100  0.024841  0.083313  0.113684   0.160948  0.003354  0.246954   1.863067   6.331802  11.368357
5          115  99   71  0.662492  0.755795  0.123242   0.144265  0.993883  0.513367  76.186541  74.823720   8.750217
```

Comment: Why does the `.multiply` not work with the `.loc` notation, but `df['coef'].mul(df['weight'])` does work?